# Unable to reliabily Match Base 64 encrypted String from strings stored in a Website: Python Program

Tags: python, regex, encryption, beautifulsoup, base64

I am Rishabh and am a beginner in Python Programming Language.. I have attempted to write a sort of an Authentication Program using Python.

**Here's What I am doing in my Program:**

1. I get the Username and Password
2. I concatenate the two strings like : ###Username:::Password
3. Then I encrypt the above concatenated string using a base64 encoding program that I saw online.(I am unfamiliar with base64 encoding and I a beginner in all the tools I have used in the below Python Program)
4. Now you get an encrypted String.
5. I have the same encrypted string hidden within the html of the blog that I created for this purpose : **https://pastarchive.blogspot.in**

**The Encrypted Strings are stored as hidden text in the html code of the page:**

```
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">HELLO !! POST</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">HELLO !! POST</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">HELLO !! POST</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">HELLO !! POST</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">HELLO !! POST</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">IIKTxK6FBJC+or4JPyQqSI0BrAevMJix//LSgGyoiETg=</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">4M3CXPZGRKUsQRqbaOPd/gajp6XD9irrM2pQ8N9MHyM=</span><br />
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">F5uxniPOSEiU2h/v1QreAx1+hXzW7GRRcJS15kYE/EM=</span><br /> 
<span style="background-color: white; display: none;">mAHuxBo7URh0QcRswXTccxq/sMTUNfbqmSaiopZxzuA=</span><br />
```

**The random characters you see in the above html code is from the website:**

6. So What I do is.. I make an encrypted string in the program as said before and I just check if the exact string exists in the website. If it is, I just display the "Successfully Logged in message" and if not I just display "Login Failed."

**The Problem:**

The problem I have is that, This method strangely works only for a few users and the rest don't succeed in finding the exact string from the website source code even though the exact encrypted string is present in the website.

Please Download the Code and run it so that you can Understand

**1. The Account which Sucessfully Logs in:**

**Username is** : USER

**Password is** : TEMPPASS

This account works perfectly as I thought

**2. The Accounts which strangely doesn't work:**

**Username is** : user2

**Password is** : CLR

Can someone tell me why the first account works perfectly fine and the later fails ? And how do I Fix this issue ? Please guide me to fix this issue as I am a beginner.

Don't get confused by the Administrator Account.. Its just a Locally verified Account..

**The Code:**

```
import requests
from getpass import getpass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import time
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

counter =1
counter2=1
import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

print("\nPlease Authenticate Yourself:")
#print("Welcome to Mantis\n")
user = raw_input("\nEnter Username:")
password= getpass("\nEnter Password:")
print "\n...................................................................."

matchstring="###"+user+":::"+password
matches=""
chkstr=matchstring
print chkstr
        ###Encryption
msg_text = chkstr.rjust(32)
secret_key = '1234567890123456'
cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_ECB)
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg_text))
#encoded = encoded.encode('string-escape')
print "Encrypted Text: \n"+encoded




##print matchstring #data sent for Authentication
if encoded == "OiKUr4N8ZT7V7hZlwvnXP2d0F1I4xtktNbZSpNotJh0=":
        print "\nHello Rishabh !! Is the Login Portal Locked ?"
        print "\n\nAdministrator Access Granted"
        counter2=2
if counter2==1:

        ###https://pastarchive.blogspot.in
        ###https://pastarchive.wordpress.com/2016/10/08/hello/
        html_content = urllib2.urlopen('https://pastarchive.blogspot.in').read()
        rematchstring=re.compile(encoded)
        matches = re.findall(encoded, html_content);


if len(matches) != 0 or counter2==2:
                print 'Sucessfully Logged in\n'
                print 'Hello '+user.upper()+" !\n"
                if user.upper()!="ADMINISTRATOR":
                 print "Thanks in Advance for using Eagle, the Advanced Data Parsing Algorithm."
                 print "\nCreator - Rishabh Raghunath, Electrical Engineering Student, MVIT\n"
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Let's Start !\n"
                print ".....................................................................\n"
if len(matches) == 0:
       print '\nUserName or Password is Incorrect\n'
       print "Please Check Your mail in case your Password has been Changed"
       print "Log in failed.\n"
       time.sleep(5)
```

Please Try to help me out with this Strange Problem.. I don't have a clue how to solve this..
Thanks.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding not an encryption. Storing such data in a webpage html (hidden or not) is not a good idea as this encoding is two way and can be read as clear text by anyone.

Comment: @marekful Yes .. I know.. I am not trying to build  a super secure Application. This is just for a small Project that I am doing and will be used by only 3 or 4 people... And moreover no one will know of this url as Python Program will be packaged into an exe file so that No one will be able to view the source code of the program.. Can You tell me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - it helps to find problem .

Comment: and check strings in HTML - maybe you put wrong strings.

Comment: @furas Yes.. I have Printed the encoded values in the Program .. And it exactly matches the string I have stored in the webpage.. The encrypted string displayed in the program exactly matches the strind that I entered into the webpage..  "Print chkstr" in the program prints the encoded string .. I used the same system before but I stored it as plain text and it worked without issue.. When I added this encoding part.. Things started to get very unreliable and only a few accounts are working as said in my post..

Comment: print html_content to see what you really get. and print counter2 in many places to see if it changes.

Comment: btw. your string may has chars which `re` use in special way. maybe use text.find(subtext)

Comment: @furas I checked the counter and it Works fine.. As said before I used to use the exact same code before just that I did not use the encryption part... So I know the counters and everything else works perfectly .. It's just that the text from the website does not get detected in some cases.. Probably what you are saying is right .. Can you give me the code how to find a way around this .. and not treat the characters as special characters ? Please run the code .. Running it once you will understand everything .. The Problem is with the " matching the string from the website part "

Comment: I am not familiar with " text.find(subtext) " As said before I am a beginner and I need a bit of help.. Please help me with the code ..

Comment: `matched = html_content.find(encoded)` , `find` returns -1 if there is no `encoded` in `html_content` or position of `encoded` in `html_content`. So now you will need `if matched != -1 or counter2 = 2`and `if  matched == -1:`

Comment: @furas .. I think the trick has worked .. I'll be back with out in a couple of minutes.. Let me check if everything works fine

Comment: Yes @furas , Everything Works perfectly fine !! Thanks for the help buddy .. But can you tell me why some accounts worked before and some didn't ? all of those encoded strings had all the special charterers in common.. What made one work and the other fail ?

Comment: probably because some `encoded` has `+` which has special meaning in `re` so `re` doesn't treat `+` as part of text. for example `1+2` searchs `12 or 112 or 1112 or etc. 111...2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you use `re` and you have `+` in `encodec`. `re` treats `+` in special way so ie. `1+2` is searching `12 or 112 or 1112 etc.`

Use `html_content.find(encoded)` which returns position of `encodec` in `html_content` or `-1`

Now you will have to use `if matched != -1 or counter2 = 2` and `if matched == -1:`

---

**BTW:** you have mess in code. It could look like this.

```
from getpass import getpass
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import urllib2
import time

# --- constants ---

SECRET_KEY = '1234567890123456'

# --- classes ---

    # empty

# --- functions ---

    # empty

# --- main ---

loggedin = False

# ------ input

print("\nPlease Authenticate Yourself:")
#print("Welcome to Mantis\n")
user = raw_input("\nEnter Username:")
password = getpass("\nEnter Password:")

print "\n...................................................................."

# ------ encrypting

matchstring = "###{}:::{}".format(user, password)

cipher = AES.new(SECRET_KEY, AES.MODE_ECB)
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(matchstring.rjust(32)))

print "Encrypted Text: \n", encoded

# ------ checking

# print matchstring #data sent for Authentication
if encoded == "eiKUr3N8ZT7V7RZlwvnXW2F0F1I4xtktNZZSpNotDh0=":
    print "\nHello Rishabh !! Is the Login Portal Locked ?"
    print "\n\nAdministrator Access Granted"
    loggedin = True
else:        
    html = urllib2.urlopen('https://passarchive.blogspot.in').read()
    loggedin = (html.find(encoded) != 1) # True or False

# ------ info

if loggedin:
    user = user.upper()
    print 'Sucessfully Logged in\n'
    print 'Hello', user, "!\n"

    if user != "ADMINISTRATOR":
        print "Thanks in Advance for using Eagle, the Advanced Data Parsing Algorithm."
        print "\nCreator - Rishabh Raghunath, Electrical Engineering Student, MVIT\n"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Let's Start !\n"
        print ".....................................................................\n"
else:
   print '\nUserName or Password is Incorrect\n'
   print "Please Check Your mail in case your Password has been Changed"
   print "Log in failed.\n"
   time.sleep(5)

# ------ end
```

Comment: Great !! Got it !! I know my code is messy .. Actually This is my first Python Program .. Its only been 2 days since I started learning Python..  so was unsure of what to do .. So I left stuff incomplete .. This is just the Authentication Part of the program I am writing.. The full program is around 4 times as big..  I'll refine and improve this code a lot as a lot of things have been written in an inefficient manner.. Anyways @furas, Thanks for helping me out buddy .. !!